# vscode java - trying to set up a project

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code

I installed vscode on windows.

Installed the Redhat extension - set the java.home settings variable to my JDK8 folder.

I've got an eclipse project and would like to compile the files in the appropriate folder.

There's a .classpath file and also a .project and .settings folder.

The .classpath file has entry for output folder.

I'm seeing trace messages - I think it's doing something (i get java warnings)...but I'm not seeing the output class files.

When I select a java file in the editor - I get the following output:

As written before I believe I've set java.home var correctly.

```html
[Trace - 7:02:28 AM] Sending request 'initialize - (0)'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Received response 'initialize - (0)' in 1995ms.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Sending notification 'initialized'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Sending notification 'workspace/didChangeConfiguration'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Sending notification 'textDocument/didOpen'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Sending request 'textDocument/codeAction - (1)'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Received notification 'language/status'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Received notification 'language/status'.
[Trace - 7:02:30 AM] Received notification 'language/status'.
[Trace - 7:02:32 AM] Received request 'client/registerCapability - (1)'.
[Trace - 7:02:32 AM] Sending response 'client/registerCapability - (1)'. Processing request took 1ms
[Trace - 7:02:32 AM] Received notification 'language/status'.
[Trace - 7:02:33 AM] Received response 'textDocument/codeAction - (1)' in 3339ms.
[Trace - 7:02:33 AM] Received notification 'textDocument/publishDiagnostics'.
```

I see these Eclipse files in the root folder - along with my java files

.classpath - most of the included project files and libs listed here.

.project

.settings folder - has just 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs file

Comment: Those files/folders with the dot in the front are Eclipse specific. So `vscode` probably not using them.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto The [Redhat extension is based on Eclipse JDT](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java), so I guess your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the trace messages and Java warnings?